# How to cache gpg key passphrase with gpg-agent and keychain on Debian 10?

Tags: debian, gpg, gpg-agent, keychain

I have a Debian 10 server. I want to send email with msmtp and I need to cache a passphrase for a gpg key. The smtp password needed by msmtp is encrypted in a file using this gpg key. msmtp will use gpg to decrypt this file to get the smtp password.

This line is present in the /etc/msmtprc file :

```
passwordeval gpg --no-tty -q -d /etc/.msmtp-password.gpg
```

**I'm trying to use gpg-agent and keychain to cache the password of the secret gpg key**. This way the system could send emails without asking password.

I want that each time I boot the server **I submit the passphrase for the gpg key only once, the passphrase for the key will be cached until the next reboot**. (If I logout and login again I shouldn't need to submit the passphrase for the gpg key until the next reboot).

I didn't succeed because when I logout from the remote host (Debian server), the gpg-agent stop. If I'm establishing a new connection via SSH keychain start a new agent with a new PID and the passphrase for the key is lost.

Below you'll find what I did and I hope useful informations. I'll be happy if you could help me.

My linux version

```
cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
```

gpg version

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.12
libgcrypt 1.8.4
```

We create a secret gpg key, a password for the key will be asked

```
gpg --gen-key
...
Nom réel : user@mdomain.tld
Adresse électronique : user@mdomain.tld
Vous avez sélectionné cette identité :
    « user@mdomain.tld <user@mdomain.tld> »
...
les clefs publique et secrète ont été créées et signées.

pub   rsa3072 2020-10-15 [SC] [expire : 2022-10-15]
      3C82AB1E9384F4A92CEBCE7077B1EDA25A942746
uid                      user@mdomain.tld <user@mdomain.tld>
sub   rsa3072 2020-10-15 [E] [expire : 2022-10-15]
```

We check the secret key

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --with-keygrip
...
sec   rsa3072 2020-10-15 [SC] [expire : 2022-10-15]
      3C82AB1E9384F4A92CEBCE7077B1EDA25A942746
      Keygrip = 47CF9E2C933761CF1021731F72603B8291BB211C
uid          [  ultime ] user@mdomain.tld <user@mdomain.tld>
ssb   rsa3072 2020-10-15 [E] [expire : 2022-10-15]
      Keygrip = 4133708B3FA225C4732A0F9FBD0053DEF937B46A
```

We look at the PID of the gpg-agent process

```
ps aux | grep gpg-agent
root       738 17.1  0.0  81204  3864 ?        SLs  16:55   0:04 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised
root       745  0.0  0.0   6092   824 pts/0    S+   16:56   0:00 grep gpg-agent
```

We check the keys known by gpg-agent

```
gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye
S KEYINFO 47CF9E2C933761CF1021731F72603B8291BB211C D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO 4133708B3FA225C4732A0F9FBD0053DEF937B46A D - - - P - - -
OK
```

We check the gpg-agent options

```
gpgconf --list-options gpg-agent
Monitor:1:0:Options contrôlant la sortie de diagnostique:0:0::::
...
default-cache-ttl:24:0:oublier les codes personnels après N secondes:3:3:N:600::
default-cache-ttl-ssh:24:1:oublier les clefs SSH après N secondes:3:3:N:1800::
max-cache-ttl:24:2:définir la durée maximale du cache de code personnel à N secondes:3:3:N:7200::
max-cache-ttl-ssh:24:2:définir la durée maximale du cache de clef SSH à N secondes:3:3:N:7200::
...
pinentry-timeout:24:1:set the Pinentry timeout to N seconds:3:3:N:0::
```

default-cache-ttl and max-cache-ttl are too low, gpg-agent will cache the passphrase only 10 minutes. This is a too short period if you intend to use keychain. We can also add a log file. Default options can be changed by adding a gpg-agent.conf file.

```
cat ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
default-cache-ttl 31536000
max-cache-ttl 31536000
log-file /var/log/gpg-agent
debug-level basic
```

We check if new gpg-agent options have been added

```
gpgconf --list-options gpg-agent

Monitor:1:0:Options contrôlant la sortie de diagnostique:0:0::::
...
default-cache-ttl:24:0:oublier les codes personnels après N secondes:3:3:N:600::31536000
default-cache-ttl-ssh:24:1:oublier les clefs SSH après N secondes:3:3:N:1800::
max-cache-ttl:24:2:définir la durée maximale du cache de code personnel à N secondes:3:3:N:7200::31536000
max-cache-ttl-ssh:24:2:définir la durée maximale du cache de clef SSH à N secondes:3:3:N:7200::
...
pinentry-timeout:24:1:set the Pinentry timeout to N seconds:3:3:N:0::
```

We reload the gpg-agent configuration to activate the new options

```
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
OK
```

Know we install keychain

```
apt install -y keychain
```

keychain version

```
keychain -V

 * keychain 2.8.5 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
```

We cache decrypted GPG keys with keychain

```
keychain --eval --agents gpg 3C82AB1E9384F4A92CEBCE7077B1EDA25A942746

 * keychain 2.8.5 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
 * Inheriting gpg-agent (738)
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:738:1; export GPG_AGENT_INFO;

 * Adding 1 gpg key(s): 3C82AB1E9384F4A92CEBCE7077B1EDA25A942746
```

Because we entered the passphrase, the decrypted GPG key is now cached by gpg-agent (look at the 1)

```
gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye
S KEYINFO 47CF9E2C933761CF1021731F72603B8291BB211C D - - 1 P - - -
S KEYINFO 4133708B3FA225C4732A0F9FBD0053DEF937B46A D - - - P - - -
OK
```

We modify the .bashrc file. On next login keychain will find the decrypted GPG key cached by gpg-agent. On next reboot keychain will ask once the passphrase for the key until the next reboot

```
cat ~/.bashrc
...
# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022
...
eval $(keychain --agents gpg)
```

In order to check default-cache-ttl and max-cache-ttl we wait 700 seconds, more than gpg-agent default configuration

```
jeudi 15 octobre 2020, 16:56:32 (UTC+0200)

jeudi 15 octobre 2020, 17:08:12 (UTC+0200)
```

We check the keys known by gpg-agent the decrypted GPG key is still cached by gpg-agent (look at the 1)

```
gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye
S KEYINFO 47CF9E2C933761CF1021731F72603B8291BB211C D - - 1 P - - -
S KEYINFO 4133708B3FA225C4732A0F9FBD0053DEF937B46A D - - - P - - -
OK
```

We create a file and encrypt it with the key (no passphrase is needed for encryption)

```
touch file.txt && gpg -e -r user@mdomain.tld file.txt
```

We decrypt the file. No passphrase is needed because the decrypted GPG key is still cached by gpg-agent after 700 seconds

```
gpg --decrypt file.txt.gpg > file.txt
gpg: chiffré avec une clef RSA de 3072 bits, identifiant 4E40A1918B514393, créée le 2020-10-15
      « user@mdomain.tld <user@mdomain.tld> »
```

We **logout and login again** to the remote host via ssh. At new login keychain can't find the previous gpg-agent with the cached key. Then keychain start a new gpg-agent but the cached key is lost...

```
* keychain 2.8.5 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
* Starting gpg-agent...
```

Regards

Answer (score 7):

Eventually I found a solution.

gpg-agent is closed after logout from bash session because it is in **supervised mode**.

Look at the file :

```
/usr/share/doc/gpg-agent/README.Debian
```

> systemd
> =======
>
> Since 2.1.17, users on machines with systemd will have their gpg-agent
> process launched automatically by systemd's user session, upon first
> access of any of the expected gpg-agent sockets (including the ssh
> socket).  systemd will also cleanly tear this process down at session
> logout.

So wee need to start gpg-agent in **daemon mode** to keep the same PID for gpg-agent across the sessions.

Before we do this we need to "mask" gpg-agent from systemd

```
systemctl --user mask --now gpg-agent.service gpg-agent.socket gpg-agent-ssh.socket gpg-agent-extra.socket gpg-agent-browser.socket
```

This can be undone with "unmask" option (see the README.Debian file).

The next time gpg-agent will be requested (eg when creating a secret key or using keychain) it will start in daemon mode and live across the sessions.

```
ps aux | grep gpg-agent
root       816  0.2  0.0  81356  3624 ?        Ss   17:19   0:04 gpg-agent
--homedir /root/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon
```

And in the .bashrc file just add :

```
eval $(keychain --eval --agents gpg secretkey)
```

After logout if you login again keychain find the right gpg-agent (look at the PID), no passphrase have been asked.

```
keychain 2.8.5 ~ http://www.funtoo.org
Found existing gpg-agent: 816
Known gpg key: 677AAEB080C1045F3D3D3532B5AE92F1F49350D1
```

and you can still decrypt file without passphrase

```
gpg --decrypt file.txt.gpg > file.txt
gpg: chiffré avec une clef RSA de 3072 bits, identifiant F1B9BB72AAECF1C7,
créée le 2020-10-16
« user@domain.tld <user@domain.tld> »
```

Hope this help.